# Plymouth animation does not properly load during startup in Ubuntu Unity 22.10

Tags: mac, plymouth, 22.10, ubuntu-unity

I am using Ubuntu Unity 22.10 in an iMac (late 2011 model).
The Plymouth animation does not load during startup, but it does load during shutdown.

How to fix this?

Here is the startup Plymouth screen, which just says "Ubuntu 22.10" on a purple screen.

[image: startup]

Here is shutdown screen with a nice logo of Ubuntu Unity.

[image: shutdown]

Comment: Are you planning to answer yourself? Considering this was released yesterday, I'd say this is a bug that should be reported in the proper place.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I don't know the answer. I will report a bug, then. But let's see if anyone can provide an answer.

Comment: Ok then I suggest to file a bug report. Unity was released as an official flavor yesterday.

Comment: Is this a bug or is it intentional? Are the four dots doing anything?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I don't know if this is a bug or a driver issue or something else. There are three white dots and one orange dot which periodically shifts its position towards right.

Comment: What should I file the bug report against? Plymouth? Unity? I am not sure if this is specific to Ubuntu Unity.

Comment: Maybe some kind person will confirm if it is a bug or not.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I may be only person in the world who is running this version of Ubuntu Unity in such an old model of iMac (which was left abandoned in my graduate student office for several years). I asked in the Telegram group for Ubuntu Unity, but there was no response. I hope someone will be able to reproduce the behavior sometime in future.